# no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When running my app on a distant server, I get the following message :

```
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
```

Using ruby on rails and  Apache/2.4.12

Don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the same error, I solved it by:

installing libpcre development libraries

debian: `apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev`

redhat: `yum install pcre pcre-devel`

After that, reinstalled the uwsgi gem:

```
gem uninstall uwsgi

gem install uwsgi
```

Lets share your result with us